# Laravel send mail with multiple check box value

Tags: laravel, checkbox

i'm trying to make inquiry form where costumer fill up form then check the value on the checkbox then once they submit form will send email to me listing all the information the customer selected, now problem is i want to change this[**event_id,requirement_id**] instead of **id** replace it with **name** those two id parameter is from my two model listed below.

```
Model:
Event:[id,name]
Requirement:[id,name]
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {



        $summary=[
            'name' => $request->fullname,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'company' => $request->company,
            'event' => $request->event_id,
            'requirement' => $request->requirement_id
        ];
        return $summary; 
       Mail::send('emails.contact-message',[
        ],function($mail) use($summary){

            $mail->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'tester');
            $mail->to('myemail@gmail.com')->subject('Contact Message');
        });
        return redirect()->back();


    }
```

This is the result of my return request:

```
{"name":"myname","email":"myemail@gmail.com","company":"mycompany","event":["1","2"],"requirement":["1","2"]}
```

As you can see the array Event has value of 1 and 2 i wanted to replace it with its name output should be [Wedding,Birthday]  i'm sorry for my bad english hope you understand me..

Comment: You have the `Event` and `Requirement` models?

Comment: yes, i have it value also has inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'd need to pull the `name` from your models. 
The following should do the trick:

```
$events = App\Event::whereIn('id', $request->event_id)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('name')
    ->toArray();

$requirements = App\Requirement::whereIn('id', $request->requirement_id)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('name')
    ->toArray();
```

*Obviously, replace `name` in the above example with the actual name field in your models. This is just an example.*

`$events` and `$requirements` will both be an array containing the names matching the ids you are supplying in your request.

You also need to change your `$summary` array as follows:

```
$summary = [
    'name' => $request->fullname,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'company' => $request->company,
    'event' => $events
    'requirement' => $requirements
];
```

Comment: how do i display the event in blade?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: email will received the list as html format from my blade emails.contact-message how do i call the event

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question right? However, since it is an array, you should loop over it as you would on any variable in a blade.